# What are the main differences between the Async Library and Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

Who can list in the most concise terms the main differences between the [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library's method of handling asynchrony and that of the rising standard Promises?

The main difference I can think of is the following: The Async library is still based on callbacks, whereas Promises provides a completely different interface, where the async process has state (i.e. resolved/rejected) and you can essentially listen for these states as if it were an event emitter.

Are there other key differences? What's a good example of a case in which Promises are needed and the Async library is wholly inadequate?

Comment: "*rising standard*"???

Comment: Promises are actual values that you can work with. `async` is only comprised of helper functions for callbacks.